# Nav Bar is turning into scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

Navigation bar drop down is bigger than the header space at the top. My intended design is for the dropdown nav to keep going over the content below but instead it gets it own scroll bar at the top?

The overflow settings for the container are Auto.

Any help would be greatly appreciated
George

Comment: hey George,share some code, plus a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would be nice

Comment: can't help with that we can't see

Comment: Sorry about that, heres a fiddle. Tried to strip as much as possible but a little bit of useless HTML left. http://jsfiddle.net/TFWf6/1/ As you can see the blue is the header and red main body. When nav is expanded it doesn't overflow on top of the body, just goes behind and a scroll is created. Thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be having issues with box model.  Since everything seems to be on overflow:auto the problem is usually the widths are being calculated too high.

In the fiddle you provide, the nav drop-down didn't work for me at all.  Try fiddling with the widths of your containers.  Here's a box model fix to try:

```
    * {
     box-sizing:border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
     webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
     max-width:100%; 
    }
```

If all that fails, save yourself some time and use a premade jQuery drop-down menu.  There are lots of lists like "35 best jQuery menus" etc, one of which may suit your needs & keep you from having to consider cases and find bugs.

Comment: Thanks Jennifer, the nav dropdown is activated when clicking the plus logo. I am developing for Rapidweaver therefore i need to take into account lots of different variations which is the cause of the problem.... Thank you for your time and answer, greatly appreciated